# Structure that mimics two flexible arrays in a struct in C

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

Currently, I have a struct `camera` that holds two fixed size variables `f` and `p`

```
struct point {
    double x, y, z;
};

struct camera {
    struct point f[5], p[5];
};
```

Making `f` and `p` flexible results in error. I followed the instructions given in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17552312/multiple-flexible-array-in-a-struct-in-c) and decided to go for non-struct variables and pass them to functions instead which resulted in long function call syntax and messy structure.

My question, although subjective, is: what is the best approach to have two flexible arrays that can be accessed via one *point* (similar to struct, etc.)?

Comment: And is `static`, thus you can only have one of them.

Comment: Variables always have a fixed size.

Comment: Are you only concern with two flexible arrays of the _same_ type?  Same array size?

Comment: @chux Yes, the type is point for both of them.

Comment: Hmmm, `struct point f[5], p[5];` looks like you want both of type `struct point` and not `double`.

Comment: Perhaps explaining why `struct camera {
    struct point *f; , struct point *p; 
};` does not solve the issue would help.  That seems like a direct solution to the higher level problem, even though it does not use a _flexible array_.

Comment: @chux please correct me if I'm wrong, but I still must allocate some memory for the arrays, mustn't I?

Comment: A `*alloc()` call is certain for any variant sized type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non *flexible array* approach follows that, IMO, addresses OP's higher level problem of "long function call syntax and messy structure" with a cleaner pair of `struct point` pointers.

```
struct camera {
    size_t size;  // add size member
    struct point *f;
    struct point *p;
};

bool camera_initialize(struct camera *cam, size_t size) {
  // Use 1 or 2 allocations
  cam->f = malloc(sizeof *(cam->f) * 2 * size);
  if (cam->f) {
    cam->p = cam->f + size;
    cam->size = size;
    return false; // success 
  } else {
    cam->p = cam->f = NULL;
    cam->size = 0;
    return size > 0; // fail if size was not 0
  }
}

void camera_uninitialize(struct camera *cam) {
  free(cam->f);
  cam->p = cam->f = NULL;
  cam->size = 0;
}
```

Sample usage

```
int main() {
  size_t n  = foo();
  struct camera cam;
  if (camera_initialize(&cam, n)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
  bar(cam.f, cam.n);
  bar(cam.p, cam.n);
  camera_uninitialize(&cam);
}
```

Comment: @sitilge  Yes corrected code should do `free(cam->f);` Post amended.

Answer (score 2):

By definition you can't have two flexible array members. A flexible array member must be the last in the structure, there can only be a single "last" element.

But I sense you apparently need to pair up `f` and `p`, so why not aggregate them? Then you can have a flexible array member of those pairs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point {
    double x, y, z;
};

struct camera {
    char dummy;
    struct {
        struct point f, p;
    } pairs[];
};

int main(void) {
    struct camera *c = malloc(sizeof(*c) + sizeof(c->pairs[0])*5);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the use of C99's support for flexible array members.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that mimics two flexible arrays of identical type: make one flexible array that holds both arrays, and add a pointer into the array at the position where the second flexible array starts:

```
struct camera {
    struct point *p;
    struct point f[];
};
```

When you allocate `camera`, provision the space for both arrays, and add it to the "raw" `sizeof(struct camera)`. Let's say your first array has `n` elements, and the second one has `m`. Then you initialize your `camera` as follows:

```
struct camera *c = malloc(sizeof(*c)+(n+m)*sizeof(struct point));
c->p = &(c->f[n]); // Point "p" to the beginning of the second array
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    c->f[i] = ... // Init points in f
}
for (int i = 0 ; i != m ; i++) {
    c->p[i] = ... // Init points in p
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `struct point *p;`? (I didn't downvote or upvote btw)